# SIMD - how to add corresponding values from 2 vectors of different element widths (char or uint8_t adding to int)

Tags: c++, c, simd, sse

Please tell me how can add values from a SIMD vector of the same type, but the values themselves, which are occupied by a different number of bytes in these SIMD vectors.

Here's an example:

```
int main()
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    int my_int_sequence[16] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };


    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[0]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[4]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[8]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[12]);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------



    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    char my_char_mask[16] = { 1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 };

    __m128i my_char_mask_m128i = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &my_char_mask[0]);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

That is, I have an array of int values ​​in the my_int_sequence array - and since all 16 int values ​​will not fit in one __m128i vector, I load these values ​​4 values ​​into the 4th __m128i vectors.

I also have an array of 16 bytes, which I also loaded into the my_char_mask_my_m128i vector.

And now I want to add to each 4 byte value of the my_int_sequence_m128i_x vectors, as if the corresponding one-byte value from the my_char_mask_my_m128i vector.

The problem is obvious that I need to add up, as it were, different dimensions. Is it possible?

Perhaps I need each byte of the vector my_char_mask_my_m128i - how to transform it into 4 bytes?

Comment: Generally, you should select either C or C++ and not both for questions.  It isn't really clear to me which language you are working with.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, with sim instructions.

Comment: I arbitrarily picked C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps I need each byte of the vector my_char_mask_my_m128i - how to transform it into 4 bytes?

You're looking for the SSE4.1 intrinsic `_mm_cvtepi8_epi32()`, which takes the first 4 (signed) 8-bit integers in the SSE vector and sign-extends them into 32-bit integers. Combine that with some shifting to move the next 4 into place for the next extension, and you get something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

void print_int4(__m128i vec) {
  alignas(16) std::int32_t ints[4];
  _mm_store_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(ints), vec);
  std::cout << '[' << ints[0] << ", " << ints[1] << ", " << ints[2] << ", "
            << ints[3] << ']';
}

int main(void) {
  alignas(16) std::int32_t 
    my_int_sequence[16] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
  alignas(16) std::int8_t
    my_char_mask[16] = { 1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 };

  __m128i char_mask = _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(my_char_mask));
  
  // Loop through the 32-bit int array 4 at a time
  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 4) {
    // Load the next 4 ints
    __m128i vec =
      _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(my_int_sequence + n));
    // Convert the next 4 chars to ints
    __m128i chars_to_add = _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(char_mask);
    // Shift out those 4 chars
    char_mask = _mm_srli_si128(char_mask, 4);
    // And add together
    __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi32(vec, chars_to_add);

    print_int4(vec);
    std::cout << " + ";
    print_int4(chars_to_add);
    std::cout << " = ";
    print_int4(sum);
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Example (Note that you usually have to tell your compiler to generate SSE 4.1 instructions - with `g++` and `clang++` use the appropriate `-march=XXXX` option or `-msse4.1`):

```sh
$ g++ -O -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -msse4.1 demo.cc
$ ./a.out
[0, 1, 2, 3] + [1, 0, 1, 1] = [1, 1, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7] + [0, 1, 0, 1] = [4, 6, 6, 8]
[8, 9, 10, 11] + [1, 1, 0, 1] = [9, 10, 10, 12]
[12, 13, 14, 15] + [0, 1, 0, 1] = [12, 14, 14, 16]
```

---

Alternative version suggested by Peter Cordes if your compiler is new enough to have `_mm_loadu_si32()`:

```cpp
  // Loop through the 32-bit int array 4 at a time
  for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 4) {
    // Load the next 4 ints
    __m128i vec =
      _mm_load_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(my_int_sequence + n));
    // Load the next 4 chars
    __m128i char_mask = _mm_loadu_si32(my_char_mask + n);
    // Convert them to ints
    __m128i chars_to_add = _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(char_mask);
    // And add together
    __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi32(vec, chars_to_add);
 
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Comment: `pmovzxbd` can take a memory source operand, so instead of 2 shuffles (`psrldq` + `pmovzxbd`) per vector after the low dword, it can make more sense to use `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32( _mm_loadu_si32(my_char_mask + 4) )` and so on.  (But that 32-bit load intrinsic is only supported in recent GCC, and was broken for a while in GCC11; see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99754.  Only fixed in GCC11.3 and later.)

Comment: Or if you need all 4 dword chunks of a 16-byte vector load expanded, instead of 4 (pmovzx) + 3 (psrldq) shuffles, you can use 6 total: punpcklbw / punpckhbw against _mm_setzero_si128, and unpack each of those results two ways.  That might need more `movdqa` instructions, but has slightly less of a shuffle-port bottleneck.  And doesn't scale up to widening to YMM vectors.  Generally I think the memory-source version is a better balance of uops for the shuffle port vs. other ports, if you can get compilers to emit that; it's a pain to do safely with intrinsics until `_mm_loadu_si32`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Never heard of `_mm_loadu_si32()`. Wonder why it took so long for gcc to include it if it's part of SSE2.

Comment: Intel didn't add it until AVX512 or later (note the `void*` arg type), maybe once they realized that `_mm_cvtsi32_si128( *(int*)ptr )` had strict-aliasing UB.  But yeah, it's pretty dumb that Intel intrinsics didn't include a clean strict-aliasing-safe 32-bit integer load for so long, many years after SSE4.1 `pmovsx/zx` instructions created another important use-case.  `_mm_castps_si128(_mm_load_ss( (float*)ptr ))` is also supposed to be strict-aliasing safe, but GCC's version of that has been buggy.

Comment: I think a lot of people used stuff like `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_loadu_si128(ptr))` and let compilers either fold the load or load past the end of the buffer in a debug build or as a missed optimization.   Related: [Loading 8 chars from memory into an \_\_m256 variable as packed single precision floats](//stackoverflow.com/q/34279513) (at least MOVQ `_mm_loadl_epi64(__m128i*)` existed for longer with a weird arg) / [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39318496)

Comment: @PeterCordes `_mm_cvtsi32_si128()`... another one I didn't know about (There's too many intrinsics!)...  Will this `_mm_loadu_si32()` work on CPUs that don't have AVX512?

Comment: Yes, as documented, it only requires SSE2.  It would normally compile to a `movd` (or `vmovd` if AVX is enabled).  And yeah, intrinsics get messy and hard to keep track of as Intel invents names.  It helps to think in terms of asm, I find, and then sort out how to keep a C compiler happy about types.

Comment: Thanks (I don't have a compiler available that has it to test myself)

Comment: Godbolt has the latest versions of all the mainstream x86 compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/zq43v5nrE